# Windows Azure Scheduler (Preview)

Tags: azure

Microsoft announced recently a new service in Azure called Scheduler. I did activated it Account -> Preview Features -> Windows Azure Scheduler -> Try it now ... but nothing has been activated under my subscription or received any confirmation email ...

This is feature is in preview mode.

Any ideas how much will take until will be in production (generally available)?

Comment: Scheduler went to general availability (GA) in April 2014 at the Build conference.  [Announcement](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/scheduler-ga-pricing-update/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment you can only access the scheduler through the REST API or through the Management libraries. You won't get an email when the feature is activated and you won't see it in the portal.

More info about the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn528946.aspx
More info about the Management libraries: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/a-complete-overview-to-get-started-with-the-windows-azure-scheduler/

Comment: I thought the same but thanks for clarification! Any ideas how long can take until will be the final release ?

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler service is now available in the Azure Management Portal. Within 2 minutes, I set up a job to issue a get request via http every 15 minutes. Working as expected. Big plans.

Comment: In May 2014 it doesn't appear I can update it via the portal. It won't save any changes (frustrating because it never held the request body on first save).